# CodeIgniter load view into array

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to load a view which contains html elements like div etc into an array, but I'm having trouble doing it. Somehow, even if I replace quotation marks, it seems to be causing error. After loading the view into the array

```
$tmp =  $this->load->view('details/action_task');
$result['html'] = str_replace('\\"','\\\\"', $tmp);

$resp = json_encode($result);
```

on chrome console, output is

```
{"code":1,"html":""}            
            <div class="text-center">Response</div>
```

As you can see `html` is empty, and its "should be" value is out of the json object. Any idea on solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As codeigniter doc provided,

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending
>   it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data
>   in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return
>   data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser.
>   Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

Try this ..

```
$tmp =  $this->load->view('details/action_task', '', true);
```

Hope it will be useful for you.